# Is NFS bidirectional?

Tags: nfs

If I write a file in the NFS-mounted folder of an NFS client, will it appear on the NFS server? Or is it possible to write a file in that folder in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it appears on the server - that's where the physical resource is.

Answer (score 1):

If the NFS share is read and write, yes it's bidirectional. If not, you will get a "read only filesystem".
NFS is just like putting a USB drive into the computer, but via internet.

Comment: *cough* "iSCSI" *cough*